# NSDictionary from NSArray using KVC

Tags: ios, cocoa

Is it possible to get an NSDictionary using KVC from a NSArray of CALayer based on key property name? I tried using -dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:, but that returns an NSArray.
Any idea?

```
   NSArray *tempArray = [self.layer.sublayers copy];
   NSArray *ListName = [self.layer.sublayers valueForKey:@"name"];

   NSDictionary *tmpD= [tempArray dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:ListName];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're asking about?

```
NSDictionary * layersByName = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[self.layer.sublayers copy]
                                                          forKeys:[self.layer.sublayers valueForKey:@"name"]];
```

`-[NSArray valueForKey:]` returns an array formed by asking each object in the reciever for its own `valueForKey:`, using the same argument.

Comment: Fantastic , that was much easier then i thought :)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know of a way to do this directly with KVC. It’s pretty simple to do just by iterating over the array, though:

```
NSMutableDictionary *layersByName = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (CALayer *layer in self.layer.sublayers)
{
    [layersByName setObject:layer forKey:layer.name];
}
```

Comment: Yep that would the simplest way of doing it . I was just wondering if it is possible using KVC